# How to properly set up Visual Studio 2013 Git Source Control Provider for Http?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tortoisegit

spent all day tryin' to sucessfully push a piece of code into our Git repo. When i generate public key for SSH I get a Git fatal error saying "Access denied" and I've read it's better for VS to go with Http.
Now, when I switch to Http  everything works well but the final `git push origin master` this time ending up with the "The remote end hung up unexpectedly".

when I run `ssh -T`.. I get the same "Permission denied".
What am I doing wrong?

Still if you know that SSH works with VS well then pls suggest what I need to try for successfully adding the public key (I go through the steps on the git website and run into Permission denied.)

but the rest works fine, I can pull data from the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got this done. The problem is in the smart http buffer chunking mechanism and whoever stuck at this ever just run this git guy:

`git config http.postBuffer 104857600` or any other number of bytes, but pls not a very big one, up to 50MB as they suggest on their website.